# iOS 14 NumberFormatter replace . (dot) with , (comma) Xcode 11.3.1

Tags: ios, swift, ios14, numberformatter, xcode11.3.1

I am facing some issues related to iOS 14 with `NumberFormatter`

```swift
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
formatter.groupingSeparator = ","
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
formatter.roundingMode = .ceiling

let value = formatter.string(from: 49.34)
```

The value I am getting on iOS 14 devices built with Xcode 11.3.1 is `49,34` instead of `49.34`.

Comment: For which locale?

Comment: You aren't setting the locale property.

Comment: @ElTomato thanks for your reply. The locale is current. For the sake of the question, let's assume I am not in Europe the is should actually have a dot. iOS 13 devices show 49.34, whereas iOS 14 shows 49,34.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks.  That's interesting.